# about Timing execution

Tags: android

i have a task: there are some data,but i want to delete it,so provides the user with options as 3 days ,5days ...to delete it. i want to use alarmmanager,but when the user close the device or modify the system time,the Timer will no longer accurately,how to avoid it .thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `AlarmManager` with an `RTC` alarm, the alarm will adjust for changes to the system time. The possible exception would be if the time change skips over the time of the alarm -- I have not tried that.

For reboots, you will need to reschedule your alarms. This is typically accomplished via a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`.